# Return all users given user chats with and the latest message in conversation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

my relationships look like this

```
A-[:CHATS_WITH]->B - denotes that the user have sent at least 1 mesg to the other user
```

then messages

```
A-[:FROM]->message-[:SENT_TO]->B
```

and vice versa

```
B-[:FROM]->message-[:SENT_TO]->A
```

and so on

now i would like to select all users a given user chats with together with the latest message between the two.

for now i have managed to get all messages between two users with this query

```
MATCH (me:user)-[:CHATS_WITH]->(other:user) WHERE me.nick = 'bazo' 
WITH me, other 
MATCH me-[:FROM|:SENT_TO]-(m:message)-[:FROM|:SENT_TO]-other  
RETURN other,m ORDER BY m.timestamp DESC
```

how can I return just the latest message for each conversation?

Answer (score 1):

Taking what you already have do you just want to tag `LIMIT 1` to the end of the query?

The preferential way in a graph store is to *manually* manage a linked list to model the interaction stream in which case you'd just select the head or tail of the list. This is because you are playing to the graphs strengths (traversal) rather than reading data out of every `Message` node.

**EDIT - Last message to each distinct contact.**

I think you'll have to collect all the messages into an ordered collection and then return the head, but this sounds like it get get very slow if you have many friends/messages.

```
MATCH (me:user)-[:CHATS_WITH]->(other:user) WHERE me.nick = 'bazo' 
WITH me, other 
MATCH me-[:FROM|:SENT_TO]-(m:message)-[:FROM|:SENT_TO]-other  
WITH other, m 
ORDER BY m.timestamp DESC
RETURN other, HEAD(COLLECT(m))
```

See: [Neo Linked Lists](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypherdoc-linked-lists.html) and [Neo Modelling a Newsfeed](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/cypher-cookbook-newsfeed.html).

Comment: limit would get me just the latest message of all of them. i need last message for each conversation